# Github Pull Request Procedure for adding more changes during a PR

Tags: github, pull-request, pull

If I submit a pull request to  Github with some changes..

And then someone edits those changes..

And I approve those changes to my PR..

And then want to make one more change to the same file..

If I go to edit the file (on the `patch branch`), I can see the proposed changes I have made, but not the ones I approved from the suggestions the other person made..

---

This makes it very confusing to know what is going to happen when the PR is accepted (if I add more changes), will the other User's changes get lost? are they added as separate patches? I'm not sure how to test this out other than setting up another github account and trying to recreate the scenario, but maybe someone can answer before I try that.

Comment: "go to edit the file", is that locally? If so, did you `git pull` the commit from the somebody else who made a change?

Comment: Or is that something that seems to happen only today? GitHub isn't reporting an incident (yet), but something's definitely wrong with commits not showing up on PR branches currently.

Comment: Now reporting an incident with actions, though it's worse than that.

Comment: Ok I figured out the issue, this is just my lack of understanding of their UI/UX (or maybe they just have bad UI/UX like Steam do). Thanks for the help

Comment: I didn't realise that it DOES actually make a separate commit, and the commit id is on the right of the 'timeline'